# How to create a hyperlink file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, links

I know this question sounds too generic but I am unable to find an answer for it.

How can I create a link (soft/hard) file which when opened, redirect me to a website with `http` protocol?

One possible way I can think of is creating a lame shell script and making it executable which can make use of a browser to open a website. But isn't there a concept of a "hyperlink file"?

Comment: You could create an HTML file with a `<meta>` redirection in it.

Comment: A link (hard/soft) opened __how__? Only from a graphical environment or from _command-line_ too?

Answer (score 17):

Add this to `target.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
</head>
</html>
```

Now if you run `firefox target.html` it will open example.com.

---

To clarify, **there is no such thing as a "hyperlink file".** You may have heard of [symbolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) and [hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link) links, but those are simply a way to refer to a file on disk - they are not URLs. From `man ln`:

> Symbolic  links  can  hold  arbitrary  text;  if  later resolved, a relative link is interpreted in relation to its parent directory.

Answer (score 10):

There are `.desktop` files:

```
$ cat ~/Desktop/Link.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Link to your site
URL=http://your-site-url.com
Icon=text-html
```

This is a possible answer when your solution needn't be command-line-based, but supposed to gain much comfort.

Of course the `.desktop` files don't have to be stored in `~/Desktop/`. I just used this location since they might be used in that location mostly.

Comment: This is missing `Type=Link`; the key is unconditionally required, and the value is required in order to use it as a web link file.

Answer (score 6):

`xdbg-open` is default application for open anything, so you can create bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if which xdg-open > /dev/null
then
  xdg-open YOUR_URL
elif which gnome-open > /dev/null
then
  gnome-open YOUR_URL
fi
```

Replace YOUR_URL accordingly, save file and make it executable (`chmod +x filename.sh`)

Comment: +1 pragmatic solution to an impossible problem :)

Answer (score 3):

One answer that has not come up yet, is using Linux’s `binfmt_misc` capabilities, to create a native executable link format that works on the kernel level!

To automatically open any `.link` files in `xdg-open`, put this inside an executable file at `/etc/local.d/binfmt_misc.start`, or any file your OS runs on startup:

```
#! /bin/sh
echo ':open-hyperlink:E::link::/usr/local/bin/open-hyperlink:' > /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc/register
```

and put the following into the `/usr/local/bin/open-hyperlink` executable:

```
#! /bin/sh
xdg-open "`cat "$1"`"
```

After that, you can just “run” `.link` files that are marked as executable via any means, and it will open the link in the browser. Command line, GUI double click, whatever you like.

```
$ echo 'http://superuser.com/questions/986527/how-to-create-a-hyperlink-file' > this-page.link
$ chmod +x this-page.link
$ ./this-page.link
[Browser opens…]
```

You can of course change the extension and file format how you like, provided you change the `open-hyperlink` script accordingly. Even Windows `.lnk` files!

Of course your kernel has to have that module available and enabled, for it to work. (I have it compiled in.)

Check out the documentation on `binfmt_misc`, as there are a lot more possibilities, e.g. with matching on a pattern instead of a file extension.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers assuming you want to do this programmatically, but if not then open the page in a browser, and drag from the address bar to the desktop or file explorer window and it should make a link.

Comment: This is dismissed, but this actually works!

Comment: Which versions of Linux does this work on? It seems more like a Windows answer than a Linux answer. Certainly on Red Hat 6, dragging a URL from Firefox ESR 52.5.1 just saved a copy of the page to disk rather than creating a link.

Comment: @Mark Booth It was a long time ago but I think I didn't notice this question was tagged Linux. Also, back then I would have been using Chrome and I assume I also tested on IE. However this should work on Linux although it may be a chrome/chromium thing.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Firefox you could install [FoxyTab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxytab/) addon and it has an option when you right click on the website's tab that's called: "Create Desktop Shortcut". It lets you save a .desktop file anywhere on your computer. On double click it will ask you how to open the file, just select Firefox and it will open the website.